# IIS Redirect Rule to redirect all subdomain traffic

Tags: regex, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, asp-classic

I have this rewrite rule defined in the web.config file on my site:

```
<rule name="RedirectWwwToNonWww" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The rule will redirect as follows:

- From: `www.example.com/test`
- To: `example.com/test`

The rule works fine, however, I would like to change the rule so that all subdomains redirect to the main site - e.g.

- From: `this.example.com/test`
- To: `example.com/test`

Or

- From: `something.example.com/test`
- To: `example.com/test`

I am struggling to work out how to change the regular expression to achieve that.

I tried this pattern:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([^.]+)\.(.*)$" />
```

That works as follows:

- From: `something.example.com/test.html`
- To: `example.com/test.html`

However, when there is no subdomain it doesn't do what I require, as I end up with:

- From: `example.com/test.html`
- To: `com/test.html`

How can I revise the rule so that subdomains redirect to the main site, but if there is no subdomain, the rule does not fire?

Answer (score -1):

I provide an idea, that is, you can use multiple conditions to match, and then set it to `logicalGrouping="MatchAny"`, as long as one of the conditions is met, a redirect will be performed. you can use this example as a reference:

```
<rule name="RedirectWwwToNonWww" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
   <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([^.]+)\.(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```